# In Jetpack compose Where to create ViewModel if i don't use Fragment or Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I'm using Stream Chat SDK for my e-commerce app. At Stream Chat's documentation they are using Activity and they can easily declare their default viewmodel by using viewModels delegation like that :

TL;DR: How to create viewModel in a composable like the way we do in Activity or Fragments like this :
`val channelListViewModel: ChannelListViewModel by viewModels { ... }`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Your ViewModel instance
    val channelListViewModel: ChannelListViewModel by viewModels { ... }
    
    setContent {
        ChatTheme { // Theme wrapper
            ChannelList(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                viewModel = channelListViewModel,
                onChannelClick = {
                    // Open the MessagesScreen
                },
            )
        }
    }
}
```

But since I'm using Jetpack Compose Navigation, I don't use any activity but MainActivty and I'm also not using any fragment. So I can't use viewModels delegation in my Screen Composables and can't decalare necessary Stream Chat viewModel.

**What I tried**

- Tried `composable` viewModel **like this** `val channelListViewModel: ChannelListViewModel = viewModel()`

But it throws error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class io.getstream.chat.android.compose.viewmodel.channels.ChannelListViewModel`

**My Screen Composable that I use Stream Chat's components and required to declare their viewModel** :

```
@Composable
fun ChannelsScreen(
    context : Context,
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel : ChannelsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        viewModel.onEvent(ChannelsEvent.ConnectUser)
    }

    val channelListViewModel: ChannelListViewModel = viewModel() //<-- Throws Exception

    ChatTheme {
        ChannelList(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            viewModel = channelListViewModel //<-- Their default viewModel,
            onChannelClick = {
                // Open the MessagesScreen
            },
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey if your `view model` doesn't contain any parameter , you can write like this in your compose navigation file

```
val channelListViewModel: ChannelListViewModel = viewModel()
```

But if it contains parameter and your are using dagger hilt then you can use `compose-hilt-navigation` library and provide `viewmodel's` instance in your composable function like this.

```
@Composable
fun Test(
viewModel : ChannelListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
){ }
```

Comment: Hi, as I said, I'm using Stream Chat SDK's own viewModel and it contains parameters but the problem is they are built in and they are not applicable to hilt. I tried your solution but it still same.

Comment: did you created channels Viewmodel or it's in built ?

Comment: Yes as i said, it's a built-in viewModel which provided by Stream Chat SDK.